# How to train bigger size images in Google Colab?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

The image file attached shows the u-net model and the related attributes to it. The image size that I want to train is 572x572x3 as in the original paper.
I am running it in colab, however, my colab keeps on crashing.
I am using:
batch size = 4
epochs = 20

How can I train this model for that image size? The image size at the output is 560x560x3.

Thank you

Architecture

[u-net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBntX.png)